# Vuejs: Handling slicing of select results

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
let slug = 'test-value/2';
let slug = 'test-value-data/10';
let slug = 'test-number-data/100';
let slug = 'data-test/1000';
let slug = 'test/10000';
```

For example, each time I select, I will get 1 slug as above. Now I want to trim the string from `/number`. For example, I want to trim the string `test-value/2` to `test-value`. So how to cut the string from `/` onwards. And common to all slugs. Please give me your opinion, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace it using regex as shown in the following example :

```js
let slug='test-value/2'
let trimmedSlug=slug.replace(/\/.*/i,'')
console.log(trimmedSlug)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.split()`

***Note**: Use this method if the slug will always have a format of `<slug without '/'>/<number>`*

```js
// Using .split();

let slug = 'test-value/2';
const trimmedSlug = slug.split('/')[0];

console.log(trimmedSlug);
```